# Primefaces make button enable on entering text

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces input text area and a primefaces button. I want the button to be enabled only when there is any value entered in the text area.

```
<p:inputTextarea id="dumpnotes" rows="10" cols="90" value="#{postProcessedDump.keyedinContent}" style="color: #000000" styleClass="inputarea" />
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{dumpController.saveDumpNotesContent}" update="dumpnotes" oncomplete="PF('dumpNotesSaveSuccessDialog').show();"/>
```

Comment: But it is not a usual pattern. Validate form on submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p:inputTextarea id="dumpnotes" rows="10" cols="90" value="#{postProcessedDump.keyedinContent}" style="color: #000000" styleClass="inputarea">
     <p:ajax event="keyup" update="saveButton" />
</p:inputTextarea>
<p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save" actionListener="#{dumpController.saveDumpNotesContent}" update="dumpnotes" oncomplete="PF('dumpNotesSaveSuccessDialog').show();" disabled="#{empty postProcessedDump.keyedinContent}" />
```

---

Edit (based on your comment):

- Try to add global="false" to not trigger ajaxStatus `<p:ajax event="keyup" global="false" update="saveButton" />`. Depending on your PrimeFaces version, you may need to strip out the event name and only write `<p:ajax global="false" update="saveButton" />`

Comment: hi, thanks for the near close answer but i do get that loading ajax primefaces logo always any way i can stop it from appearing?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please try it out and give me a feedback.

Answer (score -2):

The questions seems to be rather JavaScript related so I would try the following approach.

First I would define a JavaScript function which checks whether to enable the `commandButton` or not:

```
function validateInput() {
    if(document.getElementById('dumpnotes').value == '') {
        document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

So you just have to give `commandButton` a id (e.g. `id="button"`) and use `onkeyup` event at `inputTextarea` like this:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="dumpnotes" onkeyup="validateInput()" ... />
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Try yourself and fix answer accordingly. There are at least 2 mistakes/oversights.

Comment: @BalusC Can you give me a hint. I just tested my code and it worked fine. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/pL7ke8u7/

Comment: Use JSF components in a JSF form. And then submit the form.

Comment: Ok, I will check it on occasion. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your second answer explained it pretty well. Didn't know you can't manipulate the disabled attribute of JSF components via JavaScript. But your example makes perfekt sense and shows why it is good the way it is.

Comment: @QueryLars can you correct your answer so i can try it out? It doesnt work unfortunately.